# how to arrange button at bottom of scrollview programatically

Tags: android, android-button, android-scrollview

Here is my code to display button at bottom of scroll view programmatically.but only scrollview is displaying.button is not displaying on the screen.how to fix this.

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
        TableLayout resultLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        resultLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        resultLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
scrollView.addView(resultLayout);
        ll.addView(scrollView);

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams blp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        btn.setLayoutParams(blp);
        btn.setText("Click Me");
        //ll.addView(rl1);

        ll.addView(btn);
        setContentView(ll);
```

screen of scroll view which contains [image: tablelayout]

Comment: i m not getting u what is the problem?

Comment: here i want to place a button at bottom of scrollview but only scrollview displaying

Comment: ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); add this.@Prabha

Comment: then also button is not displaying at bottom of scrollview

Comment: post ur screen shot of what u r trying and wat u r getting

Comment: if you want to add button at bottom then you have to add it in Scroll View.... Or you have to add set padding and margin for this of button.

Comment: yes it is good idea but i want to make it static .if i place it in scrollview the button also scrolls .sooo it is not good

Comment: @Prabha so you have to add it in Linear Layout

Comment: you should better use the custom listview

Comment: are you getting what my means to say you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach... Change your ll (Linear Layout) to relative layout then put the properties for button to attach at layout bottom and and for scroll view to attach above button....hope you get my point....

Answer (score 0):

Change your current layout LinearLayout with RelativeLayout and use this params. it will work

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```

Comment: here u can watch the screen for that scrollview i want to place button at bottom and button at top right corner ,if i use u r rule then it is not possible to place my first button ar top right corner

Comment: You want to arrange two buttons or one button.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add the Footer to the Scroll View and then get the button as you wish.

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams blp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btn.setLayoutParams(blp);
    btn.setText("Click Me");
```

Then Add the view to your Scroll View.

```
ll.addFooterView(btn);
```

Comment: herooooooooo ,hey i need programmatically